# Convergence of sequence of eigenfunctions of the Laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a closed (i.e. compact without boundary) manifold with positive sectional curvature. Let us denote the $i$-th eigenfunctions of the Laplacian operator by $\phi_i$.

During some computations I encountered the expression $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(\phi_i(x))^2$. I believe this sum should converge at least for almost every $x\in M$, but I have no way to prove it or disprove it. Is there any general estimates on this type of expression for the eigenfunctions?

I include the restriction on the sectional curvature because this is what happens in my example but I don't know if it is crucial or not.

Comment: $\int \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\phi_i(x)^2 dx = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\|\phi_i(x)\|^2=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}1 =\infty$ if the eigenfunctions are normalized.

Comment: Right, I get that the integral would be infinite, but in the series the x is fixed so couldn't it happen that the series converge even though the integral is infinite?

Comment: On a circle, the eigenfunctions are $\sin(nx),\cos(nx)$ times a common normalization factor. The sum does not converge in that case.

Comment: Thanks! It’s true! Would you like to make your comment an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a circle, with inner product $\int_{0}^{2\pi}fg dx$, the normalized eigenfunctions are
$$
            \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos(nx),\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin(nx),\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
In this case, the sum in question does not converge:
$$
     \frac{1}{2\pi}1^2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}(\cos^2(nx)+\sin^2(nx))
$$